# How make a canvas window that is resizable by the user also scale down or up when the browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So at the moment I have a canvas that can be resized by the user. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to make this canvas scale down or up with the browser window when it's resized and still allow the canvas to be resized by the user without pushing the canvas outside of the browser window. I have some code that kind of gets this done with the help of this https://gist.github.com/zachstronaut/1184900, but there are two things that happen: 1.The canvas will stop resizing to a certain point. 2. When resizing the canvas in smaller browser windows it will sometimes go outside of the browser window and the only way to get it back in scale with the browser is to resize the browser window a little bit. I'm still pretty new to Javascript, so I'm a little unfamiliar with how the some things work or if what I'm trying to do is even possible. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="hxw">
                <div class="height">
                    <h3>Height</h3>
                        <select name="Height" id='height'>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                            <option value="200">200</option>
                            <option value="300">300</option>
                            <option value="400">400</option>
                            <option value="500">500</option>
                            <option value="600">600</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class=width>
                    <h3>Width</h3>
                        <select name="Width" id='width'>
                            <option value="100">8.0</option>
                            <option value="200">8.5'</option>
                            <option value="300">9.0'</option>
                            <option value="400">9.5'</option>
                            <option value="960">10.0'</option>
                            <option value="1008">10.5'</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class = "container">
        <canvas id="canvas" style=" border: 1px solid #000;">
            Your browser does not support canvas, please upgrade your browser.
        </canvas>
    </div>

<script>
document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginLeft = "auto";
document.getElementById("canvas").style.marginRight = "auto";
canvas.style.display= 'block';
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 50;
drawScreen();

formElement = document.getElementById("height");
formElement.addEventListener('change', heightChanged, true);

formElement = document.getElementById("width");
formElement.addEventListener('change', widthChanged, false);

function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function drawScreen() {
}


window.addEventListener(
'load',
function () {
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

fullscreenify(canvas);
},
false
);

function fullscreenify(canvas) {
var style = canvas.getAttribute('style') || '';
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {resize(canvas);}, false);

resize(canvas);


function resize(canvas) {
var scale = {x: 1, y: 1};
scale.x = (window.innerWidth - 40) / canvas.width;
scale.y = (window.innerHeight - 40) / canvas.height;
if (scale.x < 1 || scale.y < 1) {
scale = '1, 1';
} else if (scale.x < scale.y) {
scale = scale.x + ', ' + scale.x;
} else {
scale = scale.y + ', ' + scale.y;
}
canvas.setAttribute('style', style + ' ' + '-ms-transform-origin: center top; -webkit-transform-origin: center top; -moz-transform-origin: center top; -o-transform-origin: center top; transform-origin: center top; -ms-transform: scale(' + scale + '); -webkit-transform: scale3d(' + scale + ', 1); -moz-transform: scale(' + scale + '); -o-transform: scale(' + scale + '); transform: scale(' + scale + ');');
}
} 




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I change the canvas position to fixed and the resize() function I deduction 133 because my monitor is 1920*1080 but in the browser is 1920*947. That maybe work.

```
<div class = "container">
<canvas id="canvas" style=" border: 1px solid #000;position: fixed ;top: 10;left: 10;z-index:-1">
</canvas>
</div>

<script>
function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
//add the resize function every browser size change
  fullscreenify(canvas);
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
//add the resize function every browser size change
  fullscreenify(canvas);
}

function resize(canvas) {
var scale = {x: 1, y: 1};
scale.x = (window.innerWidth ) / canvas.width;
scale.y = (window.innerHeight - 133) / canvas.height;
//I delete the data<1 Because your size is too big so I change that
if (scale.x < scale.y) {
scale = scale.x + ', ' + scale.x;
} else {
scale = scale.y + ', ' + scale.y;
}

canvas.setAttribute('style', style + ' ' + '-ms-transform-origin: center top; -webkit-transform-origin: center top; -moz-transform-origin: center top; -o-transform-origin: center top; transform-origin: center top; -ms-transform: scale(' + scale + '); -webkit-transform: scale3d(' + scale + ', 1); -moz-transform: scale(' + scale + '); -o-transform: scale(' + scale + '); transform: scale(' + scale + ');');

}
</script>
```

Comment: This method didn't work out too well. Thanks though.